# Selectors using Buttons

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am Having 2 images and single button. By clicking on the button images need to be loaded by using selectors?

Comment: Just because it has a question mark, it's not automatically a question. You actually have to **ask** something if you want us to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this coding

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {            
    public void onClick(View v)  {          

        Drawable d1 = iv1.getDrawable();   
        Drawable d2 = iv2.getDrawable();   
        iv1.setImageDrawable(d2);
        iv2.setImageDrawable(d1);                            
    }                
  }
});
```